# Are the drawers in dual drawer dishwashers swappable?

Tags: dishwasher

We have an integrated dual drawer dishwasher made by Fisher & Paykel which is about 14 years old now.  As is usual for these drawers, the top one gets used all the time, and the bottom one rarely.

The top one has been repaired once already, and now it's no longer draining water after a wash cycle.  The repair man says we should replace the whole unit with a standard dishwasher.

I'm wondering if we can swap the bottom unit for the top, or are they different designs?  I'm told the whole thing is a single unit so I can't just replace the top unit with a new one.

I"m sorry but I don't have the exact model to hand just right now.

Comment: Did you take a tape measure to it? Most of the photos I see show a slight height difference in the drawers. Other clues, such as slide mount height, should give you your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dealt with these Fisher & Paykel *'drawer types'* before. I agree with your guy: get a $200 DW and don't look back.

According to Consumer Reports, all DWs will clean your dishes, the only difference is noise level.

Swapping the drawers with each other is probably out of the question. Live with it, or get a cheaper and better DW.

---

What you *can* swap-out is the pump assembly (I think they're the same for the upper and lower). Give that a shot before you toss it. It should pop right out, no tools needed.

Also, make sure that drawer's drain line isn't clogged with a grease plug.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll swap out the pumps to see if it works.